# How to read from a Weblogic JMS Queue with MQ Explorer?

Tags: java, jms, weblogic, message-queue, ibm-mq

I have Weblogic 12.1.2 and IBM WebSphere MQ Explorer 7.5.0.2.

In Weblogic, I created:

- JMS Server
- JMS Module
- Connection Factory
- JMS Queue

I have a JAVA program, which can send messages into this Queue.

I want to use the MQ Explorer, to read the messages from this Queue. How can I set it? What and how should I do/set in the MQ Explorer, to connect to this Queue? Could anyone give me maybe a web link? I could not find anything useful, but maybe I thought wrong how to set it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a bridge yourself.

1.Write an MDB on the weblogic that listens on the queue
2.This MDB will basically act as a client to the websphere MQ .

Basically you configure a queue on websphere MQ and using the client put messages on the queue.

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere MQ Explorer is specific to WebSphere MQ messaging provider. I am afraid it can not administer or browse JMS queue of some other JMS provider. It can read/write JNDI information to different types of JNDI providers but not read messages from other JMS providers.

Again WebSphere MQ Explorer is an Administration tool. Not recommended for getting/putting messages.